# Standard Model $\rho$ parameter with changing Electroweak gauge symmetry

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, higgs, electroweak

In Standard Model Electroweak Theory (Governed by $SU(2)_L$ gauge symmetry), $\rho$ parameter is defined as $\frac{M_W^2}{M^2_{Z^0}\cos^2{\theta_w}}=1$. Where $M_W$ and $M_{Z^0}$ are the SM $W$ and $Z^0$ boson masses respectively and $\theta_w$ is the Weinberg weak mixing angle.

Now in a hypothetical scenario, if one considers a EW theory which is governed by $SU(3)$ gauge symmetry, and latter which will spontaneously break into $(2)_\otimes (1)_$ at some energy scale (higher than SM EW symmetry breaking scale). Then whether the value of $\rho$ parameter will be changed or not?

I find one paper, [arXiv:1301.7303 [hep-ph]](https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.7303), where authors said that

> there is a global $SU(2)$ symmetry, so-called the custodial symmetry, in the Higgs sector. The $\rho$ parameter strongly depends on it.

In that case I guess the value of $\rho$ parameter will be preserved by this custodial symmetry although after changing the gauge group. But I do not properly convinced and understood. Please can any one help me to resolve this doubt?

Comment: I don't think your question can be answered as written without giving more details about what you mean by an $SU(3)$ EW theory. If you mean that you start with $SU(3)$ and then break the symmetry to the $SU(2)$ that we know, then I think whether or not the custodial symmetry is preserved will depend on exactly how you broke the symmetry. If you mean that you simply want to replace $SU(2)$ with $SU(3)$, (a) you will have many more obvious problems then the $\rho$ parameter not agreeing with measured values, (b) you'd have to work out what you even mean by the custodial symmetry in that case.

Comment: Will there be any change in the theoretical projected value of $\rho$ parameter if I initially wish to start with an $SU(3)$ and then it will spontaneously break into $SU(2)_L\otimes U(1)_Y$ at some energy scale (higher than EW symmetry breaking scale)? In such situation, I suspect the value of $\rho$ parameter will remain same at the tree level due to custodial symmetry in the Higg's sector, but it may change at the loop level (may be because of some extra particles running in the loop). I'm not sure if I'm being reasonable or not!!

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but I suspect that there will be a change to $\rho$ that depends on the scale at which you break $SU(3)$ to $SU(2)$. If that's right, you could convert measured limits on $\rho$ to a lower bound on the scale at which you break the $SU(3)$ symmetry in your model.